# I want to give my value a name in my list

Tags: python

Basically I have some values in a list that are integers. I want to give each value a name that is a string within the list so that it shows what the name of the value i have taken out is.

I have already tried putting the name in quotation marks but that does that seem to work

```
eliminate = [Couple1,Couple2,Couple3,Couple4,Couple5,Couple6]
length = len(eliminate)
FSmallest = eliminate[0]
SSmallest = eliminate[1]
print(eliminate)
gone = print(FSmallest," and ",SSmallest," have been eliminated!")
```

When i run this code. It gives me the numbers of each couple and says which number i have eliminated. I want it to tell me which couple i have eliminated. For example, "Couple1: 30 and Couple2: 20 have been eliminated!" but it does not let me add the text and the number while it is eliminating.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, but perhaps you should use a dictionary rather than a list. In any event, if you want more help you should give a [mcve].

Comment: Use a dictionary, not a list

Answer (score 2):

You have  3 options (atleast).

- Classes
- Dictionaries
- Named Tuples

---

1- Class implementation :

```
#Define the Couple class
class Couple:
    name = ""
    value = 0

    # The Constructor
    def __init__(self, the_name, the_value):
        self.name = the_name
        self.value = the_value

    # In this method we handle the output , when object is being printed.
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + " : " + str(self.value)

#Create some objects 
couple_1 = Couple('couple1', 30)
couple_2 = Couple('couple2', 20)
couple_3 = Couple('couple3', 10)
couple_4 = Couple('couple4', 40)
couple_5 = Couple('couple5', 35)

#Put them in a list
eliminate = [couple_1, couple_2, couple_3, couple_4, couple_5] 
length = len(eliminate)
FSmallest = eliminate[0]
SSmallest = eliminate[1]
print(FSmallest, ' and ', SSmallest, ' have been eliminated!')
```

Now your output will be like this :

```
couple1 : 30 and couple2 : 20 have been eliminated!
```

---

2- List of Dictionaries Implementation:

```
eliminate = [
    {'name':'couple1', 'value':30},
    {'name':'couple2', 'value':20},
    {'name':'couple3', 'value':10},
    {'name':'couple4', 'value':40},
    {'name':'couple5', 'value':35},
]
length = len(eliminate)
FSmallest = eliminate[0]
SSmallest = eliminate[1]
print(FSmallest['name'], ' : ', FSmallest['value'], ' and ',\
        SSmallest['name'], ' : ', SSmallest['value'], ' have been eliminated!')
```

Which will result the same.

---

3- Named Tuples implementation:

namedtuple is kind of a combination of class and dictionary.
we have to import it  from **collections** module.

```
from  collections import namedtuple



# Define a new namedtuple with 2 fields , name and value
# There are several ways to declare fields.
# Couple = namedtuple('Couple', ['name', 'value'])
# Couple = namedtuple('Couple', "name, value")
# Couple = namedtuple('Couple', "name value")

Couple = namedtuple('Couple', 'name value')

# Create some instances of our tuple
# We can declare the values of fields in 2 way
# First way is :
couple_1 = Couple(name='couple1', value=30)

# And the second way :
couple_2 = Couple('couple2', 20)
couple_3 = Couple('couple3', 10)
couple_4 = Couple('couple4', 40)
couple_5 = Couple('couple5', 35)

eliminate = [couple_1, couple_2, couple_3, couple_4, couple_5] 
FSmallest = eliminate[0]
FSmallest = eliminate[1]
print(FSmallest.name, ' : ', FSmallest.value, ' and ',\
        SSmallest.name, ' : ', SSmallest.value, ' have been eliminated!')
```

Comment: You should add [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields) to answer.